# Cross-domain запросы API

Tags: javascript, https, cross-domain, github-pages, openweathermap

Сделал приложение для получения погоды рядом с пользователем. После открытия не локально, выдает ошибку по поводу cross-domain запросы и говорит, что контент должен поставляться через https. Использую API openweathermap.
Как это исправить?

Вот что выдает chrome:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://nontrip.github.io/localweather/'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest
>   endpoint
>   'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=55.7485&lon=37.6184&appid=fe97d937ab684597040829d2b17fb071'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: API-ключ там случайно не для конкретного домена получаете? Было бы хорошо, если бы вы добавили полный текст ошибки.

Comment: Все правильно, это ограничение было введено как описано в https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain - только HTTP -> HTTP, или HTTPS -> HTTPS. Аналогичное объяснение можно найти на англоязычном SO (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032104/http-ajax-request-via-https-page)